# Is there a way to stream my chrome tab to my friend?

Tags: google-chrome

Let's say I find something one internet, or a youtube video I want my friend to watch. I want to stream it quickly to him. What can I do, PLUS if it comes with audio chat.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the google chrome extension [shove](https://bloxify.stream/shovewtf/index.html).Shove is a Google Chrome extension that allows you to forcibly open the browser tabs on your friend’s computer

Once the users agree to use the Shove extension, they can open links in each other’s Google Chrome browsers.

this browser extension is made to share links quickly

So, install this extension on your friend’s and your PC 
It is currently going under some re-patching

Note: that a link can be opened anytime the browser is running

Comment: yea but this just opens a link, whereas i want both of us to view the same video being ran at the same location

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: i open a tab, i see something interested, i want to call my friend/family member over. But they are in other place. i share a link. I start streaming my tab. Person joins in we start audio chat as well. I move my mouse around and highlight stuff, play a video, etc.

Comment: I don't think there is an app that does all of that in one.There is discord which has an audio call and desktop streaming feature